# How do you get the mantissa of a float in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the mantissa of a float (just to learn), but it isn't working as expected.

[image: structure of a floating point number]

The mantissa of say 5.3 is 53, right? I tried this code:

```
System.out.println(Float.floatToIntBits(5.3f) & 0x7FFFFF);
```

It printed `2726298`. Shouldn't it remove the exponent bits and leave 53? I tried plenty of things, but this always happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The base of the exponent for an IEEE floating point is *2*, not 10.

Comment: "The mantissa of say 5.3 is 53, right?". Wrong. It's binary, not base 10

Comment: You're thinking of the mantissa in terms of a *decimal* point - it's a *binary* point...

Comment: @user3580294 What do you mean?

Comment: `5.3f` isn't `5.3 x 10^1` in floating point. It's `0b01010011001100110011010 x 2^10000001` (don't know if those are the exact values, but I think what I have is somewhere in the right ballpark)

Comment: @Paul I don't understand, wouldn't there be a binary number for the mantissa that equals 53?

Comment: @user3580294 oh, i think i understand what your saying

Comment: `5.2 ~ 2726298 * 2^-19` So it looks you also typoed `5.3` instead of `5.2`.

Comment: This whole time I thought it was the exponent for a base 10 number :(

Comment: That's the whole reason it causes so much confusion -- that it's base 2. That's why for instance you can't store 0.1 exactly in a float (it's an infinitely repeating fraction in binary).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The formula for single precision following the IEEE standard is:

```
(-1)^sign + 1.Mantissa x 2^(Exponent - Bias)
```

So `5.3` base 10 is `101.0100110011001100110011` base 2

101.0100110011001100110011 = 1.010100110011001100110011 * 2^2

2^2 = 2^(exp - bias) having bias = 127 (according to the IEEE standard for single precision)
so: exp - 127 = 2 => exp = `129` base 10 or `10000001` base 2

Single precision table:

```
0 | 10000001 | 01010011001100110011001
```

Sign = 0
Exp = 129
Mantissa = 2726297

Comment: Hmmm... Seems I'm interpreting something wrong then. `Integer.toBinaryString(Float.floatToIntBits(5.3f))` prints `1000000101010011001100110011010`, and it doesn't look like the exponent there matches... Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How is the bias determined? If it's defined by IEEE and Java is IEEE-compliant shouldn't that not be an issue?

Comment: @user3580294 bias is determined by the IEEE standard, for single precision (float) it is 127 and for double precision it is 1023

Comment: @user3580294 yes, I accidentally flipped the position of Exp and Bias in the formula

Answer (score 2):

From the article [IBM: Java's new math. Floating-point numbers](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-math2/) ([in Russian](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-math2/index.html)) the simplest way to get the mantissa is:

```
public static double getMantissa(double x) {
    int exponent = Math.getExponent(x);
    return x / Math.pow(2, exponent);
}
```