# Java overloading int to long

Tags: java, type-conversion, overloading

Referring to [Java overloading - long and float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796767/java-overloading-long-and-float), which mentions rules in JLS #15

> The following rules define the direct supertype relation among the
>   primitive types:
>
> double >1 float
>
> float >1 long
>
> long >1 int
>
> int >1 char
>
> int >1 short
>
> short >1 byte
>
> where "S >1 T" means "T is a direct subtype of S", as per JLS #4.10
>   immediately above this section.

Why is the following code prints float?

```
int q = 2;
a(q);

void b(long a) {
        System.out.println("long");
}

void a(float a) {
        System.out.println("float");
}
```

Comment: did you intend both of the methods to have the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only 1 method named `a` which accept float parameter,

Java support relation (*direct supertype relation*) from `float` to `int` (using `long` in the middle):

> float > long - >  int

If you rename method `b` to `a`, you will execute method with `long` as you expected

```
void a(long a) {
        System.out.println("long");
}
```

Comment: Why conversion didn't stop at long? and if there were static void c(double c) {
  System.out.println("double");
 }, the result is not "double" but still "float"