# How to represent java float as a binary literal?

Tags: java, floating-point, binary, literals

I try to figure out how float and doubles work in Java.
[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273994/how-do-you-get-the-mantissa-of-a-float-in-java) is explained that we can represent 5.3 as

```
0 | 10000001 | 01010011001100110011001
```

But when I try to write it as a binary java literal

```
float number = 0b01000000101010011001100110011001;
System.out.println(number);
```

i get the output `1.0848567E9`.

If I use the way to represent 5.3 as binary from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157664/java-how-to-convert-a-string-of-binary-values-to-a-float-and-vice-versa)

```
int intBits = Float.floatToIntBits(5.3F);
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(intBits);
System.out.println(binary);
```

i get a completely confusing result `1000000101010011001100110011010` with 1 in the first position, which as I thought means a negative sign.

May somebody help me to understand what I do wrong?
Can I use binary java literals to represent floats and doubles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2), there is no binary float literal of the form you want.

`0b01000000101010011001100110011001` is an `int` literal, but there is a method to convert this `int` to a `float`:

```
System.out.println(Float.intBitsToFloat(0b01000000101010011001100110011001));
```

This prints `5.2999997`, because your representation isn't the most accurate. A more accurate one is:

```
0b01000000101010011001100110011010
```

Using this would print 5.3.

See also the tool [IEEE Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), which you can use to get the binary representations of floats.